# JDK problem: interrupt another thread blocked on an IO operation with signal may fail

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, kernel, signals

OpenJDK implementation(linux part) uses signal a lot to interrupt another thread blocked on a native IO operation. The basic idea is, sending a wake-up signal to the target thread will cause the blocking IO call to return with EINTR.

an examples is, interrupt blocked thread when closing the used fd asynchronously:

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c

```
    static int closefd(int fd1, int fd2) {
        ...
        /*
         * Send a wakeup signal to all threads blocked on this
         * file descriptor.
         */
        threadEntry_t *curr = fdEntry->threads;
        while (curr != NULL) {
            curr->intr = 1;
            pthread_kill( curr->thr, sigWakeup );
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        ...
    }
```

another example is to interrupt a socket channel:

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.java

```
protected void implCloseSelectableChannel() throws IOException {
    ...
    // Signal native threads, if needed.  If a target thread is not
    // currently blocked in an I/O operation then no harm is done since
    // the signal handler doesn't actually do anything.
    //
    if (readerThread != 0)
        NativeThread.signal(readerThread);

    if (writerThread != 0)
        NativeThread.signal(writerThread);
    ...
}
```

But, there may be race in which the blocked thread will miss the signal and won't be interrupted.

To demonstrate, I wrote a small piece of test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig) {
    printf("singal\n");
}

int main() {
    // set-up an interrupting signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, handler);

    // not blocking operation, prepare to block
    // if the wake-up signal arrived during this
    // operation. we'll miss it.
    for (int i = 0; i < 2100000000; ++i) {
        int j = i * i;
    }
    printf("not blocking operation done\n");

    // blocking io operation
    unsigned int remain = sleep(10);
    printf("blocking io operation done, remain %u\n", remain);

    return 0;
}
```

If the wake-up signal arrived just before the blocked thread enter the kernel to await IO, eg., executing some wrapper code of glibc, the blocked thread will miss this signal forever and failed to be interrupted.

The output when signal arrived before IO looks like:

```
./a.out
^Csingal
^Csingal
^Csingal
^Csingal
^Csingal
not blocking operation done
blocking io operation done, remain 0
```

And the output when signal arrived after blocked by IO:

```
./a.out
not blocking operation done
^Csingal
blocking io operation done, remain 6
```

Is it a JDK bug or did I miss something?

Comment: Interesting observation, but your question is, well, missing an actual question...

Comment: Note that you can manually check if a thread has been interrupted with [Thread.interrupted()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--).

Comment: @AliceRyhl still blocked, won't work

Comment: Java doesnt use signals explicitly but does need to handle them on a best effort basis.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it a JDK bug or did I miss something?"

you missed an important point: a bug is discrepancy between specification and implementation. The Java specification says nothing about linux signals, which means it can react to them in any way and this cannot be qualified as a bug.

To proof existence of a bug in JDK, you have to find an assertion in [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) which you think is violated and create a test which demonstrates that JVM behaves differently than it is prescribed by that assertion. Since all assertions in the JVM spec are expressed in terms of bytecode, the test has to be written in Java (or any other JVM language) and compiled to a class file.